# Django Multiple ForeignKey and same related name

Tags: python, django

I want to use `user` foreignkey to many models. I can't use this type of method. Is any possible way to give common name to all foreignkey. I want to access `x.created` or `x.updated` in every template.

```
class Model_one(models.Model):
    --
    --
    created = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="created")
    updated = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="updated")


class Model_two(models.Model):
    --
    --
    created = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="created")
    updated = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="updated")


class Model_three(models.Model):
    --
    --
    created = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="created")
    updated = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="updated")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Using `related_name` as the same name as the field is redundant. If you get rid of this you could probably use it the way you were intending.

Comment: You get access x.created or x.updated without "related_name". related_name need for [backward relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: @ErDmKo , without related name, multiple foreignKey to same table not allowed. is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generalize your approach you could do something like that:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="created_%(class)s_objects")
    updated = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="updated_%(class)s_objects")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ModelOne(BaseModel):
    # your model one fields


class ModelTwo(BaseModel):
    # your model two fields
```

With this approach you

- don't need to define the same fields on all models explicitly because you inherit from `BaseModel`.
- The [special syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name) automatically creates backward-relations with the right class names. Therefore `user.created_modelone_objects.all()` will give you all the objects an user has created.